# Retrieval of title from json from indexed object array ios using swiftyjson

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking, swifty-json

**JSON**

```
    {
  "321" : {
    "title" : "xyz",
    "pageid" : 321,
    "ns" : 0
  },
  "172" : {
    "pageimage" : "xyzc.jpg",
    "pageid" : 172,
    "title" : "xyzcc",
    "ns" : 0,
    "thumbnail" : {
      "width" : 100,
      "height" : 57,
      "source" : "https:\/\/upload.abcd.org\/wikipedia\/commons\/thumb\/d\/de\/xyz.jpg\/100px-xyz.jpg"
    }
  },
  "224" : {
    "pageimage" : "abc.jpg",
    "pageid" : 224,
    "title" : "dasf",
    "ns" : 0,
    "thumbnail" : {
      "width" : 98,
      "height" : 100,
      "source" : "http:\/\/example.org\/images\/thumb\/2\/26\/skfdb.jpg\/98px-586px-dasdfsa.jpg"
    }
  },
  "825" : {
    "title" : "efkjdsb",
    "pageid" : 825,
    "ns" : 0
  },
  "229" : {
    "title" : "eafewg",
    "pageid" : 229,
    "ns" : 0
  }
```

How can I access the "title" and "thumbnail": "source" in the JSON file after retrieval from the JSONresponse using `SwiftyJSON`?

"321", "172" can change and depends. There multiple number of more objects in the array of same format.

Some objects have thumbnail object some don't as well.

How shall I fetch `title` and and `thumbnail->source` to a `TableView` with image and label to create a list.

(Using `Swift` language)
Im Retrieving json using `AFNetworking`

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
        manager.GET(url, parameters: nil, success: {(operation, responseObject) -> Void in

            let responsejson = JSON(responseObject!)


            print("\n \n \n \n \n \n  Retrieved = \n\(responsejson)")

            let items = responsejson.count
            print("Items : \(items)")
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us what you have try.

Comment: Problem im facing is due to the indexing of each object array with number. Hence im not able to fetch them.

Comment: I dont have code to show. Because as im new to this format of json in ios

Comment: @NiravD can u Help me sort this issue if u are familiar

Comment: For that at least you need to at least show how you are getting this JSON response.

Comment: im using AFNetworking for retrieving the JSONResponse

Comment: the JSON object in swiftyjson supports fast enumeration, just do a for (key,obj) in <#nameofJSONobject#> and you can access the data. Subsequently you might want to store the key for faster access

Comment: Could u share the code for retrieving title from json , please

Comment: @AthulL.S You want object that have both `title` and `thumbnail` right?

Comment: Yes I do need both

Comment: during the enumeration you can access a particular data by obj["title"] or obj["thumbnail"]

Comment: can u type the code for shwing in print atleast @BenOng

Comment: Like i did for items for displaying count

Comment: @AthulL.S Check my solution once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a code like this to get each value:

```
for (key,obj) in responsejson {
    print(obj["title"])
    print(obj["thumbnail"]["source"])

}
```

Comment: Note that theKeyIWant is a string

Comment: example of key?

Comment: what do u prefer as key string tobe entered here?

Comment: the key is one of the numbers like "224" or "321"

Comment: i cant enter the key...there are 135 objects in the real JSON

Comment: with different different keys

Comment: I edited the answer, that is actually all you need to get it to work, it is just that usually people do not use every value from a data upon retrieval therefore certain checks are done to filter them off

Comment: how to get from an object inside named  thumbails : Source

Comment: change "title" to "thumbnail"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129962/discussion-between-ben-ong-and-athul-l-s).

Comment: Im able to retrieve it by addding                print(obj["thumbnail"]["source"])

Comment: I have never attempted such a direct access before, but if it works you can do so, I suggested the method of casting obj["thumbnail"] into JSON as you might store that for later use but if there is no such needs accessing directly will indeed be faster

Answer (score 1):

Try to enumerate through you `JSON` response and check both `title` and `thumbnail` is available if use use it.

```
for (key,item) in responsejson  {
    if let title :String = item["title"].stringValue{
        print(title)
        if let thumbnail : String = item["thumbnail"]["source"].stringValue{
            print(thumbnail)
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can also use Swift native `Dictionary`.

```
for (key,item) in responsejson.dictionaryValue {
    if let title = item["title"] as? String {
         print(title)
         if let thumbnailDic = item["thumbnail"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            print(thumbnail)
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: if condition is false. Not entering inside the loop

Comment: @AthulL.S I have already told you it will give you object that has both title and thumbnail.

Comment: if let title = item["title"] as? String {
                    print(title)
                 //   print(thumbnail)
                }

Comment: i meant it is not printing title

Comment: if condition is notcoming true to enter its loop

Comment: Try just printing key out side the if condition and check what is printing and give response here.

Comment: mm..Let me try it now

Comment: thanxs ..IM gettting nw

Comment: @AthulL.S What was the issue then?

Comment: if let title :String = item["title"].stringValue{
                    print(title)
                 //   print(thumbnail)
                }

Comment: condition was the issue...I fixed it

Comment: @AthulL.S I have edited answer with Swift Native Dictionary Check it once.